# How can we import all tables in RDBMS into a Hive custom database?

Tags: sqoop

I want to "import-all-tables" using sqoop from mysql to a Hive Custom Database ( Not Hive default Database )

Steps tried:

1. Create a custom database in hive under "/user/hive/warehouse/Custom.db"
2. Assigned all permissions for this directory- so there will be NO issues in writing into this directory by sqoop.
3. Used below command with option "--hive-database" option on CDH5.7 VM :

   ```
   sqoop import-all-tables 
   --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" 
   --username retail_dba 
   --password cloudera 
   --hive-database "/user/hive/warehouse/sqoop_import_retail.db"
   ```

Tables created in hive `default` database only, not in the custom DB in this case: "`sqoop_import_retail.db`"

Else its trying to creates tables in the previous HDFS directories (`/user/cloudera/categories`), and error out stating table already exists:

```
16/08/30 00:07:14 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/categories already exists
16/08/30 00:07:14 ERROR tool.ImportAllTablesTool: Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/categories already exists
[cloudera@quickstart etc]$
```

How to address this issues?
 1. Creating tables in hive custom DB
2. Flushing previous directory references with Sqoop.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention `--hive-import` in your command. So, it will import it to HDFS under `/user/cloudera/` in your case.

You are exceuting query again. That's why getting Exception

```
Output directory hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/categories already exists
```

Modify import command:

`sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" --username retail_dba --password cloudera --hive-database custom --hive-import`

It will fetch all the tables from `retail_db` of MySQL and create corresponding table to `custom` database  in hive.

Comment: I am still having the error with option --hive-import.
I had a discussion with other member Durga and understand how sqoop imports data. It first copies data to a staging area ( in this case /user/cloudera) and then moves it finally to the destination directory ( hive-warehouse / hive-database). 
So in the failure cases the tables exist on the /user/cloudera for some reason and they act as orphans for the next run- and making this to fail prematurely.
Removing the files frm the location /user/cloudera and running worked..

Comment: Refer@ Load comand 
16/08/30 03:47:47 DEBUG hive.TableDefWriter: Create statement: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `/user/hive/warehouse/sqoop_import_retail.db`.`categories` ( `category_id` INT, `category_department_id` INT, `category_name` STRING) COMMENT 'Imported by sqoop on 2016/08/30 03:47:47' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001' LINES TERMINATED BY '\012' STORED AS TEXTFILE
16/08/30 03:47:47 DEBUG hive.TableDefWriter: Load statement: LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/categories' INTO TABLE `/user/hive/warehouse/sqoop_import_retail.db`.`categories`